# especially + noun at the end of the sentence

Tags: word-choice

> Data shows a rise of problems with mental health due to the internet, **especially social media**.

Is such construction proper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is perfectly correct to use a noun after 'especially' at the end of a sentence.

My mother likes alcoholic drinks, especially gin.

I love vegetables, especially onions.

Wild animals can be dangerous, especially lions.

Comment: Just to be sure - my construction is also correct? 'due to the internet, especially social media'

Comment: It's fine. Why did you think it might not be?

Comment: It looked somehow awkward to me when I created it. It's probably because I used that construction in this way for the first time. Thanks for the help!

Comment: The end of a sentence is a very common place to put an expression starting 'especially'.